# Label does not update when textvariable changes (Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm completely new to Tkinter and I can't seem to make it work, even when copy/pasting codes from tutorials. More specifically, the following code for instance

```
Mafenetre = Tk()

Button(Mafenetre, text = 'quit.', command = Mafenetre.destroy).pack()


v = StringVar()
v.set("New Text!")
Label(Mafenetre, relief='solid', textvariable=v).pack()


Mafenetre.mainloop()
```

does not show New Text (but does show the 'quit' button). More generally, any use I've made (even copy/pasted code) of the textvariable attribute does not produce any text. What am I not understanding ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your code looks fine. When I run your program I see "New Text!". How are you running your program?

Comment: Unable to duplicate; "New Text!" shows up in the label for me.  A likely problem (if your actual code isn't *exactly* what you posted here) is that you created your `StringVar` before calling `Tk()` to initialize things.

Comment: I'm using IEP. The code I displayed is exactly the one I'm running (apart from the line from tkinter import *). It's very odd, I'm plainly and dumbly following tutorials here... For instance when I use text="New Text!" instead of textvar it works just fine. Could it be that it is a setting issue ?

Comment: It sounds like a bug in IEP. Your code should work for any version of tkinter.

Comment: Try `v = StringVar(Mafenetre)`.

Comment: Novel you're a genius thank you so much it's working ! Thank you to everyone who's helped me !

Answer (score 1):

Tkinter variables need a tk instance. So use:

```
v=StringVar(Mafenetre)
```